# Onclick feature over image

Tags: javascript, c#, html, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to make text appear when the user clicks on an image but cannt get it to work. could someone please help me i'm doing it using JavaScript.

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you show us the code you've written that doesn't work so we can help to fix it.

Comment: in the JavaScript i've got the following code: <img src='img/middle.fw.png' onclick='alert("Text appears...")'/>     and in the html i've linked the Javascript in the header: <script src="JavaScript1.js"></script> this is my first time making a webpage so sorry if I sound stupid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, [and an example:](http://jsfiddle.net/buncwgeL/)

`<img src='http://placehold.it/350x150' onclick='alert("Text appears...")'/>`

[Here's another example showing how you can do the alert and write text to a div](http://jsfiddle.net/buncwgeL/1/), since the alert is of limited value.  You can also just write to the div

Answer (score 0):

Mikeb's code works if you are writing it in HTML. If you are using Javascript and have a reference to you  element:

```
var imgElement = document.getElementByID('WhateverYouPutAsTheID') //or get ref some other way
imgElement.onclick = function() { alert('Message you want to display'); };
```

I hope this works for you!

Comment: i am writing it in HTML using visual studio c# but still cannot seem to get it working. Thanks for the help

Comment: I'm lost. You just said that you were writing it in HTML using C#. Do you mean that you are generating HTML using C#? If so, are you getting any error messages? Any additional info you can provide will make it easier to figure out what is going on.

Comment: yes you are correct I am generating HTML using C# and i am not getting any errors it builds and opens i just cant click on the image and get the text to appear

Comment: I have got this code in the html: <script>
                        document.getElementById("network").onclick = function () { myFunction() };

                        function myFunction() {
                        document.getElementById("network").innerHTML = "welcome";
                        }
                        </script>

Comment: Try putting a semi colon after the "myfunction()" in you assignment of your "onclick" event. Try this: document.getElementById("network").onclick = function () { myFunction(); };